# how can i Generates and returns a random integer between lower (inclusive) and upper (exclusive)

Tags: java

```
public static int randInt (int lower, int upper) {

}
```

Generates and returns a random integer between lower (inclusive) and upper (exclusive)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: @user1275616: I rolled back your edit since it seems like completely different question then the initial one. If you want to ask a **different** question - ask a new question, and dob't edit the current. Also - when you do - please format it **much** better then how you editted this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Remember that you can generate `X~U[a,b)` with: `a + Y` where `Y~U[0,b-a)`

You can generate `Y` with `nextInt(b-a)`

[in here `X~U[a,b)` means `X` is a random variable that is uniformly distributed at range `[a,b)` ]

It seems homework, so I leave the actual implementation of it to you, it should be fairly easy using these guidelines.

Comment: can you pls check this ?

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new here :(

Comment: http://www11.0zz0.com/2012/03/17/11/316353288.jpg\